# Javascript - put mapped data into groups

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I am mapping data from an "animals" array of objects like so:

```
renderAnimals() {
        return Object.entries(this.state.animals).map(([key, value], i) => {
            return (
                <div key={key}>
                    <b>{this.state.animals[key].group}</b>
                    <p>{this.state.animals[key].name}</p>
                </div>
            )
        })
    }
```

This animal object is divided into two groups currently and the data gets rendered like this:

**Sea Animals**
Shark

**Sea Animals**
Fish

**Sea Animals**
Octopus

**Farm Animals**
Pig

**Farm Animals**
Cow

**Farm Animals**
Chicken

My question is: how can I map it so that all animal groups are automatically in one div and the group name doesn't get repeated so it looks like this?

**Sea Animals**
Shark,
Fish,
Octopus

**Farm Animals**
Pig,
Cow,
Chicken

The "animals" object looks like this:

```
    animals:
     [0: {group: "Sea Animals", name: "Shark"},
      1: {group: "Sea Animals", name: "Fish"}]
```

Appreciate any input, thank you!

Comment: can you show us how that animals objects looks like ?

Comment: @MihaiT edited my Post

Comment: is `animals` an array or an object? it seems you mapping over it as if its an object but in your example it looks like an array

Comment: @Sagivb.g Sorry for the misunderstanding, I edited it. It's an array of objects.

Comment: So why are you iterating with `Object.entries`?

Comment: People answered your question. They took the time to make answers + explanations. It would be nice of you to take the time and rate them and maybe a thank you for their time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either write javascript solution or you can go for utility library lodash. There's no need to use Object.entries. You have to group them and iterate through the grouped key-values. I've given both in my answer:

1. This is pure javascript solution.

   ```js
   const groupBy =(xs, key) => {
     return xs.reduce((rv, x) => {
       (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
       return rv;
     }, {});
   };

   const animals = [{group: "Sea Animals", name: "Shark"},
     {group: "Sea Animals", name: "Fish"},
     {group: "Farm Animal", name: "Cow"}];
   const groupedData = groupBy(animals, "group");
   console.log(groupedData);
   ```
2. Or you can install lodash - `npm install lodash --save` and `import { groupBy } from "lodash";`. You can just do `groupBy(this.state.animals, "group")`;

Answer (score 0):

You can group the array into an `object` that each key has the relevant array of animals, only then iterate over the keys and for each key (group name) iterate over the animals.

Here is a running example:

```js
const items = [
  { group: "Sea Animals", name: "Shark" },
  { group: "Farm Animals", name: "Cow" },
  { group: "Farm Animals", name: "Pig" },
  { group: "Sea Animals", name: "Octopus" },
  { group: "Sea Animals", name: "Chicken" },
  { group: "Sea Animals", name: "fish" }
];

const groupedItems = items => {
  return items.reduce((groupTable, current) => {
    if (!groupTable[current.group]) {
      // no key yet
      groupTable[current.group] = [];
    }
    groupTable[current.group].push(current.name);

    return groupTable;
  }, {});
};

function App() {
  const groupedBy = groupedItems(items);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {Object.entries(groupedBy).map(([groupName, groupAnimals], i) => {
        return (
          <div key={i}>
            <b>{groupName}</b>
            {groupAnimals.map(animal => (
              <p>{animal}</p>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You use Object.entries but `animals` is an Array of objects, not an object.

use object.values together with reduce to group your objects into another array of objects but you will have just 2 objects ( Because you group them by the ' animal group ' ) . The objects will look like `{ animalGroup : string, names: array[] }` , and then in the render function just use again object values to render what you want.

See below

```js
const animals = [{
    group: "Sea Animals",
    name: "Shark"
  },
  {
    group: "Sea Animals",
    name: "Fish"
  },
  {
    group: "Sea Animals",
    name: "Kraken"
  },
  {
    group: "Farm Animals",
    name: "Pig"
  },
  {
    group: "Farm Animals",
    name: "Cow"
  },
  {
    group: "Farm Animals",
    name: "Tazmanian Devil"
  },
]



const animalsArr = Object.values(animals.reduce((result, {group,name}) => {
    if (!result[group]) {
      result[group] = { group, name : []} 
    }
    result[group].name.push(name);
    return result;
}, {}));

function Animals() {
  return (
    <div className="Animals">
      {Object.values(animalsArr).map((value,index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <p>{value.group} : {value.name + ''}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const animalsContainer = document.getElementById("animals");
ReactDOM.render(<Animals />, animalsContainer);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="animals" />
```